# EditText inputType special case to get only number and a special symbol

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my scenario,

I just wanna get only number and a particular special character like $ at the end of the EditText field.

Ex:    234.34$

I don't wanna validate after entering this input, but rather user can only enter decimal number and at the end this special character.

Some one please help me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following (progromatically)

```
ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
ed.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.$"));
```

you can define whatever characters you want within the `DigitsKeyListener.getInstance`

or if dont want the user to enter the $ sign and you want to be entered manually after the user finishes editting...

```
@Override
protected OnFocusChangeListener getOnFocusChangeListener() {
return new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            //Member variable in the class which contains an EditText
            CurrencyTextbox.this.hadFocus = true;
        } else {
            // Thes EditText has lost focus
            Log.v(TAG, "Lost focus.");
            if (CurrencyTextbox.this.hadFocus) {
                // We previously had focus, now we lost it, format the user input!
                // Get current value of the Textbox
                String value = CurrencyTextbox.this.textbox.getText().toString();
                // Formatting the user input
                value = String.format(//Doing some formatting);
                // Reset the had focus
                CurrencyTextbox.this.hadFocus = false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why I can't enter special symbols in that Edit text.  ?

Comment: You can identify any symbol you want within `DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("")` glad I helped you out

Comment: Yes It works.  I have marked your answer as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Edit text add the property `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

Comment: Or you can add hint to your Edittext with $ symbol and let the input be numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your EditText `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

In the Class file add a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` as following code and in the method `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` add "$" at the end of the text in EditText.

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_text_box);
input.addTextChangedListener(onInputTextChanged);

public TextWatcher onInputTextChanged = new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        // Add "$" at the end of text in EditText
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accept only numbers and phone number type using java code

```
EditText number1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edittext); 
    number1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
     number1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("Replace with your special characters”));
```

This code will avoid lot of validations after reading input